# Numbers not distributed evenly

Tags: normal-distribution

We have a large (2000+) set of numbers that we are assigning grades to.

This is the logic

[image]

But no matter how many different data sets I use, grades fall into A, C, or F, i.e.

[image]

I understand that A has a large range, i.e. anything less than <85 and so does F, i.e anything greater than 115%

Whereas B, C, D have range of 10 points. But if that's the case, are some locations being graded as C?

To me, something seems amiss.

Is there some sort of mathematical phenomena (such as Birthday Paradox, where if you get 23 people in a room, two of them have same birthday)?

This has been puzzling me for over a week.

#### Update

I believe I implemented the formula correctly, so this question is a mathematical one

Here is screenshot

[image]

Comment: For starters, the range of grade values (which should be somewhere between say 75 and 125) are not at all reflected in the chart you show (which ranges from 1.667 to 5.0).  It could be you are committing some great error in how you are constructing your report.

Comment: @MichaelTiemann I am using Grand Average = 100 as an example. No matter what different set and ranges of numbers I use, I find the same trend.

Comment: You need to clarify what you're asking. I can't even tell if you have a question about the mathematics or a question about how you've implemented the formulas in a spreadsheet. (And no, the birthday paradox doesn't seem relevant at all.)

Comment: @GregMartin I updated question. It's about the mathematics.

Comment: As it turns out, the answer is that the implementation is wrong. You need .05 several places where you have .5.

Comment: @GregMartin Holy Cannoli!!!!!! Ok, I will fix this in the office tomorrow .... Thank you so much!!!!!